# postfix delivers mail for support@domain to root's mailbox

Tags: centos, postfix-mta

I'm trying new postfix setup. I tried few tutorials, but whatever I do, all mail sent to support@mydomain.com and info@mydomain.com is delivered to root. All other recipients are fine.

The OS is CentOS 6.9 minimal setup. (dedicated server at Hetzner)

I gave up.

/etc/postfix/aliases

```
root@mydomain.com             support
postmaster@mydomain.com       support
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
myhostname = realhostname
mydomain = realdomain.com
myorigin = $mydomain
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
inet_interfaces = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
mailbox_command =
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

/var/log/maillog

```
Aug 18 12:44:44 allfortips postfix/local[3409]: AC9F63600A7: to=<root@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<support@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.13, delays=0.13/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
```

What can I check to see why this happens?

Edit: Just noticed that info@ has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to check **/etc/aliases** Don't!

After editing the file, run **newaliases**